# Visual Studio SDKs

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk

I've inherited a project that is trying to link to libraries in the following location:

C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A\Lib/x64/

I've installed VS2012 but I haven't been able to figure out how to get this library on my machine.  Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to install an update to get this directory on your machine.  It is used to create apps that still run on XP, the original release of VS2012 did not support that.  Which requires at least Update 2, you should however strongly favor Update 3 to avoid a bug.

It should have already reminded you that this update is available.  You can [go here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) to kick-start that.

Do make sure your machine boots the 64-bit version of Windows or you won't be able to test your program.